# CSS/JQUERY – Check if website is being viewed on Smart TV or Smart Fridge

Tags: html, jquery, css, television, smart-device

I've designed a website which users are encouraged to use on their phones and laptops. However, when I view the website on a Smart Fridge and Smart TV, I want it to display a div which shows the logo and a QR code to scan.

Is there a CSS query which can detect whether the user is viewing the website from fridge/tv? I cannot find any valuable reference.

Example:

```
@media (fridge) {
#qr-code {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Generally not. Due to the number of devices and manufacturers, there is no good way to determine the device type. Most use the Window or Screen Width to determine the device type. There are some other tricks you can use to determine the resolution, which can help identify a SmartTV versus a device like a Fridge or Tesla screen.

Comment: Perhaps you could define what capabilities you are interested in the device having and tackle it from that direction? Dimensions of screen is the obvious one, whether or not touch screen is another and there may be others. What for example makes it impossible to run your  code on a smart TV? This should help narrow things down.